# How to set Text Field full width of parent View in navigator bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield, constraints

I am new to iOS dev, and I'm trying to develop a browser which looks like below.

[image]

I set the width and height of `Bar View` in code. It works fine.

[image]

And then add constraints of `Url Text Field` in `pin`

[image]

The width is not restricted to the parent container `barView` (which is full-width)

[image]

I wonder is there something special of width of Text Field? I dig around but haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`UINavigationBar` doesn't expose the Autolayout engine to us properly.
Partly because it just started supporting Autolayout since iOS 11!

Check out [this gist by Yoshimasa Niwa](https://gist.github.com/niw/569b49648fcab22124e1d12c195fe595) for more information:

> `UINavigationBar` has been using manual lay outing until iOS 10, so all its content views like `titleView` has been directly child view of the `UINavigationBar`. However, since iOS 11, it is using auto layout with bunch of layout guides to lay out its content views in its own internal container view, `_UINavigationBarContentView`.

---

In general, to put positioning constraints on any `view`, we need a reference to it's `superview` or a sibling view.

```
someView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.leadingAnchor)
someView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.trailingAnchor)
```

---

Similarly, in the case of `UINavigationBar`, we need a reference to `titleView`'s superview which is `_UINavigationBarContentView`.

Practically, we could traverse `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews` to get a hold of `_UINavigationBarContentView` to apply a whole bunch of anchors to `titleView` but since `_UINavigationBarContentView` is private, it should not be referenced at all.
Who knows if the hierarchy changes in future iOS releases, or maybe they change the name, or dunno wtf they do.

Bottomline: It just seems to me right now that there's no safe way to apply proper leading/trailing/top/bottom/etc constraints on `titleView`.*
<sub>*Correct me if I am wrong</sub>

---

#### Suggestion:

However if your `urlTextField` was the `titleView` itself instead of `barView` i.e. something like:

[image: TextField as TitleView]

You could safely get away with:

```
urlTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
urlTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.size.width - 16).isActive = true
urlTextField.layoutIfNeeded()
```

To see this:

[image: Simulator Output]

Answer (score 1):

To set UITextField on UINavigationBar with full width use below code

create a UITextField variable with fixed Rect calculated from screen size. you can change based on your requirement.

```
   lazy   var navTxtField:UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40))
```

In your viewWillAppear

```
    navTxtField.placeholder = "Search here..."
    navTxtField.text = ""
    self.navTxtField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textDidChangeText(_:)), for: .editingChanged) // if you need to identify text changes in textfield measn you can use this otherwise ignore this

    let leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: navTxtField) 
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?.append(leftNavBarButton)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why is width of my TextField adjust to its content [screenshot #2], instead of responding to constraints added in storyboard, leading 0pt and trailing 0pt of superview `barView` (whose width is set in viewDidLoad).

Comment: In your case you add textfield to titleView so it will take titleView's area only. So you have to add it as navigationBarButtonItem. Via interfacebuilder you can't add UITextField to navigationbarbutton item so we have to do that in programatical way. @iplus26

Comment: I set width of `barView` to fullwidth in code and it works. However, when I add constraints to Text Field, width of Text Field doesn't adjust but the width of `barView` adjust to its son Text Field, which is strange to me.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your programming way. It works when I add rect to frame of Text Field also. I would like to keep the question open to find out if there is some more information about the autolayout issue. Thank you again